# Removing salutations from full name using regex

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have names like `"John Connele MCA MD"` and `"John O'Connele"` and I used this regex `"s*[A-Z]+(?:\.|\b)"`.

```
String fullName = "John O'Connele MCA MD";
fullName = fullName.replaceAll("s*[A-Z]+(?:\.|\b)","").trim;
System.out.println(fullName)
```

The purpose of the regex is to remove only the salutations and title the output I get is `"John Connele"` while correct output should be `"John O'Connele"`

Comment: Your code does not compile - the regex is malformed. Also you don't seem to be looking for "salutations" to remove, but rather titles. You'll need to search for an adequate criterium, e.g. maybe whitespace followed by sequences of capitalized-only letters and whitespaces.

Comment: sometimes the name can be "John O'Connele, MCA,MD so i dont think I could rely on the whitespaces

Comment: Well you'll need to find a suitable rule - mine was only an example.

Comment: you could try `{2,}` instead of the `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
   \W*\b[A-Z]+\b(?!'\b)\.?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gutQnJ/1).

**Details**

- `\W*` - any 0+ non-word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary (we need to match a whole word)
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - end of word (a word boundary)
- `(?!'\b)` - no `'` followed with a word char is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\.?` - 1 or 0 `.` chars.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/Xo4vyr) (note all backslashes are double inside string literals to denote literal backslashes, regex escapes):

```
String fullName = "John O'Connele MCA,MD.";
fullName = fullName.replaceAll("\\W*\\b[A-Z]+\\b(?!'\\b)\\.?","").trim();
System.out.println(fullName); // => John O'Connele
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

\s[A-Z]{2,}+